# Bootstrap Popover AND a Modal (hover and click)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Scenario: user profile. I would like to be able to display a user name with a popover that displays a limited amount of information from the user profile. So far, I have that part working. I can build it on the fly and have it do what I need. The popover works perfectly.

What I would **also** like to do is have the user be able to click on the user name and bring up a Bootstrap modal form with more information about the user (if provided). The first problem I am seeing is that it appears the data-toggle attribute can only have a single setting:

```
echo '<a href="#" class="trigger userprof" data-toggle="popover" data-target="#userModal" data-popover-content="#content' . $user_row['user_id'] . '">' . $user_row['user_name'] . '</a>';
```

In that example, if I add the modal to the data-toggle attribute it doesn't seem to do me much good.

I have discovered by tinkering (and that is why the class 'userprof' in the code above), that a JavaScript click event can be triggered (right now all I'm doing is a basic JS alert dialog to test), but from there I would want to load the modal. I am not sure if I can make it all work.

I have a set of functions I've used successfully for another modal (calling this one 'userModal') that I got some help from someone here a while back with -- is it possible to call that from the click event?

```
// code to open the modal with the caption and description:
$('#userModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event)
{
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
   var title = button.data('title'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
   var body = button.data('body'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
   var modal = $(this);
   modal.find('.modal-title').text( title );
   modal.find('.modal-body').append( body );
});

// when modal closes, clear out the body:
$('#userModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function ()
{
    $(this).find(".modal-body").text('');
});
```

Since these are "anonymous" functions I am not sure I can call them ... feeling a bit lost in the code here. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great. I'd even be willing to consider a different idea, but I would like this kind of functionality *(hover and click)* for this situation and possibly something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're listening for the modal to show itself, when the DOM is showing the modal.

try using something like this, and use a button or a link with `data-toggle="modal"`

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#userModal', function ()
{
    $(this).find(".modal-body").text('');
});
```

for reference https://jsfiddle.net/y063mu4t/1/

Comment: The big issue is that I already have a data-toggle for the popover on the link, and it appears that Bootstrap doesn't like multiple data-toggle settings.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show you both a tooltip and the modal both with data-toggle

Comment: Anthony -- thanks. I see now what you are doing. You're setting one data-toggle on the 'span', and one on the link. That seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.userprof', function(){
    $('#userModal').modal('show'); 
});
```

To make your callback function work, you need to add according data-* attribute to each of the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Getting closer. Thanks. I have added attributes data-title and data-body, with some dummy text to start with, and they seem to be undefined, despite they're being there with text values. The modal dialog loads, but it is empty. I am not sure if it understands the object (the link) that is calling it?